# Notepad won't launch, doesn't show in task manager

Tags: windows-10

Today I tried to launch Notepad and nothing appeared to happen -- no error, nothing in the taskbar.  I checked Task Manager and the Detail tab shows no entry for `notepad.exe`.

There are two `notepad.exe` binaries, one in `C:\Windows` and one in `C:\Windows\system32`.  Both show the same behavior (not launching), and both have a SHA256 sum of `CA2837031952C32BC1639A416F5C2ADCEEBF33507D216E554A3B47B17C52E9B1`.  It's interesting that the file was updated on 10 Sept, but the checksum is the same on another system where Notepad works fine.

`sfc /scannow` showed an error, so I ran `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`.  This failed with `0x800f081f, The source files could not be found`, so per [this page](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/dism-fails-source-files-could-not-be-found) I ran `Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` which reported success.  I ran `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` (success) and `sfc /scannow` (success), but notepad still won't run.

I deleted `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Notepad`, still won't run; rebooted, still won't run.

I rebooted in Safe Mode, won't run; `sfc /scannow` again, won't run.

I haven't identified any other programs that won't run (Wordpad is fine, for example) and recent Defender scans come back clean.

Comment: "Tried to launch Notepad" is much too vague. What EXACTLY did you do? If you clicked on an icon for a shortcut (.lnk) file, did you examine all the properties of that file?

Comment: Sorry, to be clear: I have tried typing "notepad" in the Start menu and clicking the result, as well as double-clicking "notepad.exe" in Explorer (under `C:\Windows` as well as under `C:\Windows\system32`).  I have also tried just typing `notepad` in the Run (WIN+R) dialog.  All behave the same way, i.e. no launch, no error, nothing in Task Manager.

Comment: Been mucking about in the Windows\SxS directory recently? Anything interesting in Registry key "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\notepad.exe" ? How's your PATH env. variable?

Comment: Is there a "Previous Versions" of notepad.exe to be found from the file properties dialog? Update may have corrupted the poor thing.

Comment: In order: I have not touched SxS. There is no `notepad.exe` under the registry path you listed (but there are `ngen.exe` and `onenote.exe` so I'm in the right place). Nothing stands out in PATH but it does end with `C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` which is mildly interesting since I just started using the Microsoft Store last weekend when I got Game Pass Ultimate.  (Probably not related?)  The Previous Versions tab is empty for both binaries.

Comment: Also maybe interesting: `c:\windows\notepad.exe` has a generic binary icon (same as `ntoskrnl.exe` in System32) but the binary in System32 has the normal Notepad icon -- even though the binaries have the same checksum.  Isn't the icon built into the binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sfc /scannow showed an error, so I ran DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image
> /RestoreHealth.  This failed with 0x800f081f, The source files could
> not be found. I have tried typing "notepad" in the Start menu and
> clicking the result.

Something is badly broken.  DISM and SFC should both run and correct errors and Notepad will start from either Start Menu or Task Manager.

It is now time to run a Windows 10 Repair Install

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Start with the option to Keep Everything.

> Notes for Repair Install:
>
> 1. This process will upgrade all applicable drivers.
> 2. This process will make you uninstall incompatible software
> 3. This process will not fix damaged User Profiles. Must use Keep Nothing

Comment: I will look at the Repair Install when I have some time but I want to make sure it's clear, only the first run of DISM failed, then `StartComponentCleanup` seems to have fixed it because running `RestoreHealth` again reported everything was successful.

Comment: You can Repair and Keep Everything to clean up your machine (I have done this) or Keep Nothing to do a fresh install if you wish.

Comment: Is there any way to tell exactly what is actually broken? I was kind of hoping for more advice about maybe seeing what's happening when I try to launch, some kind of extra logging or what to look for in Event Viewer, rather than just "wipe the thing and start over". I do see a lot more troubleshooting pages that suggest this as a cure all these days...

Comment: It is hard to tell. You said you had two occurrences of Notepad which may or may not be the reason. Other errors could cause this as well. That is why I suggest a Repair Install to correct as many things as possible.

Comment: I just checked a "normal" (working) system and found the same thing -- identical binaries in `Windows` and `System32`. The former has a generic icon. When I run Notepad from the start menu or with the Run dialog, it picks the one in `System32`.

Comment: I do not see this on my three Windows 10 systems here including one Insider machine.

Comment: I just checked 2 more systems here and they all have the same files (and except the problem system can launch Notepad fine). Are all your systems (except I guess Insider) on 2004?

Comment: Yes, all V2004.  You may have some legacy software installed. Notepad has worked fine for me for a very long time and any time I needed it on a client machine.  You should try the Repair as suggested on the problem computer.

Comment: Took me a month and a bit to get round to this, but I did the "keep everything" reinstall and Notepad is working again.  I'm marking this as the answer, but I'd still love to know exactly what happened.

Comment: One thing about Repair Installs is that we do not always know. I work on "Why" as I get the opportunity, but I first like things to work.   Glad Notepad is working again for you.